# @react-native-firebase/admob doesn't work even when I use TestIds

Tags: firebase, react-native, admob

I`m trying to insert ads in my React Native app using the library @react-native-firebase/admob. I did all creation and configuration steps on my Admob Account, and also integrate firebase account.

However, when I try to run my App with a BannerAd, it shows the error bellow, even when I try with TestIds:

```
[admob/error-code-no-fill] The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.]
```

Libraries in package.json:

```
"@react-native-firebase/admob": "^11.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.2.0",
```

My code that cause this error:

```
import { BannerAd, BannerAdSize, TestIds } from '@react-native-firebase/admob'

...

const testBannerId = TestIds.BANNER

...

<BannerAd
  unitId={testBannerId}
  size={BannerAdSize.BANNER}
  onAdClosed={() => console.log('closed')}
  onAdFailedToLoad={(error: any) => console.log(error)}
  onAdLeftApplication={() => console.log('Ad left application')}
  onAdLoaded={() => console.log('Ad loaded')}
  onAdOpened={() => console.log('Ad opened')}
/>
```

I appreciate if someone give me a light in my case.

Thanks all!